# syntax error, unexpected end of file, expecting "elseif" or "else" or "endif"

Tags: syntax-error, tailwind-css, bulma, laravel-10, laravel-breeze

I modify the breeze login to personalize it. I use bulma instead of tailwind but I encounter an error
`syntax error, unexpected end of file, expecting "elseif" or "else" or "endif"`
which shouldn't be there because the only condition `@if@endif` that I have is:

```
@if (Route::has('password.request'))
    <a>
        {{ __('Forgot your password?') }}
    </a>
@endif
```

and I have close it

I have try to remove the condition `@if@endif` but I have the same error